# ssrs 2008 R2 rounding Fill expression value to match displayed percentage

Tags: reporting-services, rounding, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a textbox which I need to colour format based on an expression.

Here is the value in the textbox:

```
=iif(Fields!TotalStartsForTurnaround.Value=0
,Fields!Within2Hours.Value/Fields!TotalStartsForTurnaround.Value)
```

The textbox is formatted to show the value as percentage with 0 decimal places.

I have the following fill colour criteria:

```
If value <90% then red
If value >=90% and <96% then Orange
if value >=96% then Green
```

The Fill expression is as follows:

```
=iif(Fields!TotalStartsForTurnaround.Value=0,"White"
  ,iif((Fields!Within2Hours.Value/Fields!TotalStartsForTurnaround.Value)<0.9
    ,"Red"
    ,iif((Fields!Within2Hours.Value/Fields!TotalStartsForTurnaround.Value)>=0.9
        and (Fields!Within2Hours.Value/Fields!TotalStartsForTurnaround.Value)<0.96
      ,"Orange"
      ,"Green")))
```

However say I have a value of 0.89999. The colour of the textbox is correct but because the percentage is being rounded.. the display value is 90%.

How can I get the fill expression to match up with the rounding of the percentage so that colour coding matches the percentage displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying your expression for clarity, instead of using something like:

```
=IIf(Fields!MyValue.Value < 0.9, "Green", "Red")
```

In your `BackgroundColor` expression, `Round` the value being checked in the same way it is rounded in the the formatting:

```
=IIf(Round(Fields!MyValue.Value, 1) < 0.9, "Green", "Red")
```

This should mean what the user is seeing and what is being used in the colour check should match up.

A couple of things that might help:

- Add a calculated field to your Dataset to represent the result of `Fields!Within2Hours.Value/Fields!TotalStartsForTurnaround.Value` - this will be usable in subsequent report expressions and help make the code easier to follow.
- Use a `Switch` expression to determine the colour instead of a series of nested `IIf` statements.